# Get the name of a street and maxspeed given a node id

Tags: overpass-api, osrm

I need to obtain the name and maxspeed given the node id.

I can obtain that using the [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) and [longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude), but I don’t know how do this using a node id. Example:

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way[maxspeed](around:5.0,36.6870970,-4.4531804);out%20center;
```

#### Output

```
{
    "version": 0.6,
    "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.61.5 4133829e",
    "osm3s": {
        "timestamp_osm_base": "2023-10-13T14:02:30Z",
        "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "way",
            "id": 60727865,
            "center": {
                "lat": 36.6880970,
                "lon": -4.4541804
            },
            "nodes": [
                746325927,
                3650408717,
                7067178413,
                3547298108,
                3650408715,
                760219855,
                5245547649,
                5417047626,
                3650408712,
                760219851
            ],
            "tags": {
                "cycleway:right": "shared_lane",
                "highway": "primary",
                "lanes": "2",
                "lit": "yes",
                **"maxspeed": "50",**
                "name": "Avenida Molière",
                "oneway": "yes",
                "parking:right:orientation": "diagonal",
                "sidewalk": "right",
                "surface": "asphalt"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The sense is that I can obtain the nodes using the */nearest/* query of the OSRM API. The idea is obtain the nearest point and its node id, and the attack [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) with the node id to obtain the *maxpspeed* information.

#### Solved

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node(id:5417047626);out;
```

This better:

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node(id:5417047626);way(bn);out geom;
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Node 5417047626 doesn't include any maxspeed details. Typically, you will only find maxspeed information on ways, and not the nodes. So what you have to do is to find a corresponding way for a given node id, and extract the maxspeed info from the way (if it exists in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
osrm_url = "https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/36.6880970,-4.4541804?nearest"
osrm_response = requests.get(osrm_url)
osrm_json = osrm_response.json()
if "waypoints" not in osrm_json:
    print("No nodes near the specified latitude and longitude")
    exit(1)
node_id = osrm_json["waypoints"][0]["nodes"][0]
overpass_url = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node(id={node_id});out skeleton;"
overpass_response = requests.get(overpass_url.format(node_id=node_id))
overpass_json = overpass_response.json()
node = overpass_json["elements"][0]
name = node["tags"]["name"]
maxspeed = node["tags"]["maxspeed"]
print(name, maxspeed)
```